# egrep output lines with maximum count of word "foo"

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have lines that look something like this:

```
foo, foo6, foo foo large foo, la foo
```

I only want the lines that have no more than 3 `foo`'s, and I would like to use `egrep` to extract said lines.

I thought that something like `(foo){0,3}` would work, but it outputs lines with more than 3 `foo`'s on them as well.

Answer (score 5):

Use `grep -v` to filter out lines with 4 `foo`s, like this:

```
egrep -v '(foo.*){4}' filename
```